# How to get variable value in sciprt

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

I have this script in Product page

```
 <script type="javascript">
    viewmodel = {"here is Json data"}
 </script>
```

My question is how can I get the `ViewModel` value from another page. For instance I want to get this JSON data in Home page.

[This is simply that i want to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RczOK.png)

Comment: Try make your question a little less abstract. Where do you want to pass the value of the viewmodel variable? Can you provide a piece of code for this problem?

Comment: I just want to get this viewmodel variable's value which is contains Json data from another page

Comment: can you check again my question i added picture that i want to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var viewmodel = <?php echo $yourViewModelVar;?>;
</script>
```

You can use just  as shortener syntax, but I prefer full  tags

Comment: can you check again my question i added picture that i want to do

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
<script>
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
    $("#demo").html(obj.name);
</script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: can you check again my question i added picture that i want to do

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get a Javascript variable from another page, because javascript is front end. How are you fetching that JSON data?